# Does Islam mention Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma in its scripture?

Tags: other-religions, hindu

Is there any mention of the religion Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma (earlier name of Hinduism) in any of the Islamic scriptures?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Made it more significant now.

Answer (score 2):

The Quran does not mention the name of any religion other than Islam.  <sup>[3:19](https://quran.com/3/19)</sup>

And it doesn't *name* the followers of any other religion, except for *Yahud* (Jews), *Nasarah* (Christians), *Majus* (Zoroastrians) and *Sabieen* (Sabeans) and includes the others by saying *Mushrikeen* (those who do shirk). <sup>[22:17](https://quran.com/22/17)</sup>

Same goes for the well known hadith of the Prophet, though the region of India is mentioned in some hadith as هند (Hind) and (possibly) the people as زط (Zut).

Comment: What is the meaning of Zut?

Comment: @user22632 The Jutt People of Northern India. A few tribes of them were resettled in Greater Khorasan region during Umayyad Empire era IIRC as a buffer zone. They didn't last long If my memory serves me right.

Comment: The word mushrikeen is synonymous to polytheists.